# Is there a limited number of entities returned by Olingo getEntitySetIteratorRequest() method

Tags: java, odata, olingo

I am trying to read a set of entities from an odata v4 service using olingo.

If I query the entity set from Postman, I get a response listing 51 entities.

If I try the same thing in code using olingo, only 35 entities are returned in the ODataEntitySetIterator returned by olingo. I don't have a filter defined.

```
URI qryUri = client.newURIBuilder(serviceRoot)
.appendEntitySetSegment('Sites')     
.build();

ODataRetrieveResponse<ODataEntitySetIterator<ODataEntitySet, ODataEntity>> 
response = client.getRetrieveRequestFactory()
.getEntitySetIteratorRequest(qryUri)
.execute();

ODataEntitySetIterator<ODataEntitySet, ODataEntity> iterator =  
response.getBody();
```

When I iterate round the returned ODataEntitySetIterator I find that 36 instances of the site entity have been returned, when I expect 51.

Any you tell me why the number of entities returned is lower than expected?

Is there a limit to the amount of data an odata request can return?

Comment: Which version of olingo client are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.4.0

Comment: Where is `ODataEntity` coming from. I am not able to find it. For me its `ClientEntity` are the Server and client libraries of Olingo getting mixed somewhere?